# SonarQube isn't showing openclover coverage report

Tags: sonarqube, clover

I'm having difficulties setting up [openclover 4.2.0](http://openclover.org/doc/openclover-4.2.0-release-notes.html) to work with SonarQube 6.0.

Here's what I have in logs:

```
[INFO] [08:42:14.706] Sensor org.sonar.plugins.clover.CloverSensor
[INFO] [08:42:14.707] 2/2 source files have been analyzed
[INFO] [08:42:14.707] Parsing /workspace/topparent/biz/target/site/clover/clover.xml
[WARN] [08:42:14.709] Resource /workspace/topparent/biz/src/main/java/biz/BizClass.java was not found.
[WARN] [08:42:14.710] Resource /workspace/topparent/biz/src/main/java/integration/FirstClass.java was not found.
[INFO] [08:42:14.711] Matched files in report : 0%
[WARN] [08:42:14.711] 2 files in clover report did not match any file in SonarQube Index : /workspace/topparent/biz/src/main/java/biz/BizClass.java, /workspace/topparent/biz/src/main/java/integration/FirstClass.java, 
[INFO] [08:42:14.711] Sensor org.sonar.plugins.clover.CloverSensor (done) | time=5ms
```

I don't know why the .java files aren't found, the path is correct. I guess I don't see the coverage report because of this:

```
Matched files in report : 0%
```

But why?

Comment: Are the paths in the clover report relative or absolute?

Comment: The property is set like this
`-Dsonar.clover.reportPath=target/site/clover/clover.xml`

and paths in clover.xml are absolute
https://pastebin.com/5A4mGdwh

Comment: Are the paths _inside_ the clover report, the ones _to_ the files, relative or absolute?

Comment: Sorry, I don't get the question. What do you mean by "clover report"? If it's the clover.xml file, I gave the link to the file in the previous comment.

Comment: `sonar.clover.reportPath` can also be set in your Maven pom as a property.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was doing:

```
mvn clover:setup verify clover:aggregate clover:clover sonar:sonar -sonar.host.url=...
```

I broke this into 2 separate commands:

```
mvn clover:setup verify clover:aggregate clover:clover
```

then

```
mvn sonar:sonar -sonar.host.url=...
```

And it works now.

```
Matched files in report : 100%
```